# How do I change the direction of slideToggle to up using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, java, slidetoggle

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2" ></div>
  <div class="head" style="background-color: #1c94c4; text-align: center; cursor: pointer;"> Chat</div>
  <div class="chat" style="display: none;width:auto;height: 200px;background:whitesmoke;">
    <div class="body" style="overflow:auto; overflow-x: hidden;height: 90%; width:auto;"></div>
    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Type a message..." style="float:left; resize: none; width:84%; height:34px; margin-right:4" ></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 7px;height:34px ">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.head').click(function () {
      $('.chat').slideToggle({
        direction: "up"
      }, 300);
    })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question into the form of a question, and to clarify that this is jQuery related. I also indented your code to make it more readable. I suggest you alsoe separate your styles out from inline into CSS and put all of your code in a jsfiddle to make things easier for people who want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to hide it initially. From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/#entry-longdesc):

> If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown.

You can hide it with a single CSS property (`display: none`), which you can put in a class or add directly, or with `.hide()`.

Also, `direction` is not a documented option, and your sample code actually [works correctly in this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yaq3988p/) (because you do have `display:none`). You might want to make sure you're using a current version of jQuery and don't have any console errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the [jQuery .slideToggle() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) you'll see `direction` is not an available option. However, by moving your .head element below the toggling element we can achieve what I believe you are after.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.head').click(function () {
    $('.chat').slideToggle(300);
  })
})
```

```css
.chat {
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  background: whitesmoke;
}
.form-control {
  float: left;
  resize: none;
  width: 84%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.btn {
  padding: 7px;
  height: 34px;
}
.head {
  clear: left;
  background-color: #1c94c4;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat">
  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Type a message..."></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</div>
<div class="head"> Chat</div>
```